# From Transparent To Solid Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help. Can someone tell me why this code isn't working?
I linked HTML with CSS and JavaScript properly.
I tried everything, and I checked the code carefully, but I didn't find any mistake.
The code looks good but when I scroll, nothing happens.

I want to change the background color of the navbar from transparent to solid when scrolling.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 200)
        {
            $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
        }
        else
        {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('solid');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.navbar{ 
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
    position:fixed;
    transition:background-color 1s ease;
}

/*--Class to add on scroll--*/
.navbar.solid{
    background-color:#000;
    transition:background-color 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
   <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><h2>Plant<span>.</span></h2></a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-nav">
      <ul class="nav">
         <li class="nav-links active">Home</li>
         <li class="nav-links">About</li>
         <li class="nav-links">Contact</li>
         <li class="nav-links link4">Hire Us</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Matija.  Would you please edit your question to let us know what it's supposed to do and what specifically isn't working?

Comment: I want to change the background color of the navigation when scrolling. I think my code is good, but when I scroll, nothing happens.

Comment: It's working for me fine when I load jQuery. Check that you have added the link to cdn or however you are doing it

Comment: Also `transition:background-color 1s ease;` on .navbar.solid is redundant. On .navbar only is just enough

Comment: Okay, I'll try.

Comment: I taked a quick look. The event scroll is fired more that one time when you scroll. The problem could be this

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem. I didn't import the jQuery link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am not sure if I've interpreted your question correctly as it's not very clear as to what exactly isn't working. But I think what you mean to imply is that the jquery code isn't working as expected. You might try executing this snippet:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.navbar').toggleClass('solid', $(this).scrollTop() > 200);
});
```

Now you can define the 'solid' class however you want to and I hope it'll work!

Also, make sure that you've imported the jquery CDN properly.

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping. I didn't import the jQuery link.